Bragg's Law: Don't Waves have to Overlap to Interfere?
This might be an absurd question, but I just want to make sure I am understanding things right; I have not touched trigonometry in a two years and things are not adding up.
The common model to depict Bragg's law is similar to this one here:

The graphic shows constructive interference that would be caught by the detector. However, I also know that it is a given that waves HAVE to overlap in order to interfere; this is a high school understanding. However, no model of Bragg's law shows re-emitted waves overlapping, so...they technically do not interfere.
Obviously, there is something excluded from the common model. For example, I played around in a drawing program and made this that allows for interference:

Is the common model for Bragg's a simplification?

The waves do overlap and so interfere because as you can imagine that the source is very wide compared to the difference between the atomic planes, for example millimetres to nanometres. The source is thus a plane wave that diffracts  by interacting the planes of atoms in the crystal.

I believe that first diagram is constructed to emphasize the path difference between the two incident rays, which is how Bragg's law was derived. Perhaps the images on Wikipedia can be considered a more accurate representation of what's really happening.

The distance from X-ray source to sample is on the order of 0.1 meter, and the distance from sample to detector is similar. On the other hand, the separation between lattice planes is on the order of nanometers, or $\pu{E-9 m}$. When a wave packet (or a single photon) hits two neighboring layers, the opening angle is close to zero, i.e. the incident angle is virtually identical. Similarly, scattered waves originating from neighboring layers reach a given point on the detector coming from virtually identical direction. The diagrams simplify this to show parallel beams.

The graphic shows constructive interference that would be caught by the detector. However, I also know that it is a given that waves HAVE to overlap in order to interfere;

They do overlap, at the detector. You have spherical waves coming off the scattering atoms (not shown in the diagram the OP posted) and ask how they interfere at the detector.
Interference occurs at the detector because a single wave hits both layers of the sample. Constructive interference is maximal when the scattered waves have the same phase at the detector. Overall, the X-ray has a random phase (a superposition of random phase waves), but it still works because single photons hit both layers.
When estimating the difference in path from source via scatterer to detector, you assume an infinite distance of the source and detector (i.e. parallel lines); because of the dimensions given above, it is a very good estimate.
How many layers can show interference depends on the transverse (spatial) coherence of the X-ray beam. In one example (see figure 5), it was determined as a couple of micrometers, so hundreds to thousands of layers.
More about figures
Most figures describing Bragg's law focus on one aspect and leave out others. When an atom (or its electrons) scatter light, it goes in all directions. The wavelength and the phase are unchanged:

The reason many figures are showing waves in one direction only is because that is where we put the detector. Also, most of the incoming wave is not scattered at all but goes straight through (as we know from old-style X-ray imaging at the doctor's office).
When there are two scattering centers, the two scattered waves (observed in a certain direction) don't necessarily have the same phase because the distance from source via scattering atom to detector depends on the position of the atom.

You can show that when the atom is on a certain plane, the distance is the same, and when it is on a parallel plane at a certain distance away, the distance is different by a multiple of a wavelength, so the phase is the same. This leads to either Bragg's law or to the Laue conditions, a different way to describe in which direction there is constructive interference (and "spots" on the detector).
The pictures with multiple waves hitting atoms and multiple waves scattered are confusing and misleading. Sometimes, these images show a phase change at the scattering atom, which is not what happens (except a bit with anomalous scattering, which is an advanced topics because it is no longer purely elastic).

"Interference only works if the incoming waves have the same phase" -- Did you mean the same wavelength?  Interference is a function of phase difference.  Waves do not have to have the same phase to interfere. Waves having the same phase do produce the maximum constructive interference, however, and those with opposite phase, the maximum destructive interference.

@JohnBollinger Yes, I updated it. Same phase means you see a signal. If the phase from the next layer is off by even just a bit, the one from the following layers is off by more, and the total from all layers is almost nothing.

So, it only matters that the waves are the same phase at the sensor? I see that what is actually happening when X-Rays strike the sample is a little more complicated, and the model used for when X-Rays hit crystal planes is a simplified logic that extends from what is happening at the sensor; to some degree we do not care about what the X-Ray does when it bombards atoms, as we only want to detect constructive re-emission on the other side, so the common model used (the one I used) is all XRD cares about. Is this correct?

@BigRigz Yes, that is the gist. Of course, without elastic scattering at the sample, nothing interesting would be observed at the detector.

How large (wide) is a wave? the answer is not obvious -- the evanescent field of a wave in a piece of glass in air (i.e., total internal reflection in a glass fiber) can be detected some distance outside that fiber. Though the wavelength of a red laser might be 635 nm, the evanescent field can be detected a few microns outside that fiber.
So, yes, interference can occur between waves apparently separated by some distance -- and atomic spacing in a crystal is far closer than a wavelength of visible light, or (most) X-rays. Not until gamma rays does the wavelength approach that of atomic spacing.
BTW, the evanescent field falls off quite rapidly, exponentially, and the act of detecting it removes some power from the system, so reflection is then not total. Consider the "width" of a wave as a quantum effect, similar to the "diameter" of an electron.
